# Classes with String Switches

Tags: c#

```
 class AddItemOption
{
    //Fields that contain class data
    string input = Console.ReadLine(); 
   //Methods that define class functionality
    public string myFunction(string Value)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case "Umbrella":
               Console.WriteLine("Umbrella is selected");
               break;
            case "Rain Coat":
               Console.WriteLine("Raincoat is selected");
               break;
            case "Boots":
                Console.WriteLine("Boots is selected"); 
                break;
            case "Hood":
                Console.WriteLine("Hood is selected");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Input not reconized, please choose another item");
                break;


        }

    }
```

I get the error "Not all code paths return a value". It is from myFunction(string Value). I'm not sure how to return this, or what to put in the parameter to get it to work. Do I need something below it too? I am new to classes. Please tell me if I'm doing this all wrong or if that is where the switch statement should go!

```
   public AddItemOption(string input) 

        {


        }
```

FROM Shyju I changed it to:

```
class AddItemOptionOne
{
    //Fields that contain class data
    string input = Console.ReadLine(); 
   //Methods that define class functionality
    public string myFunction(string Value)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case "Key Chain":
               return "Key Chain is selected";
               break;
            case "Leather Armor":
               return "Leather Armor is selected";
               break;
            case "Boots":
                return "Boots is selected"; 
                break;
            case "Sword":
                return "Sword is selected";
                break;
            default:
                return "Input not reconized, please choose another item";
                break;


        }
    }
```

However, it does not recognize the breaks. "Unreachable Code Detected"

Comment: Side note: `Console.ReadLine();` in field definition? This is very unusual approach to initializing fields... bordering with "can you really do that?"... consider more direct initialization (i.e. in "ReadInputFromConsole" method or passing values to constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method has a return type of `string`. That means your method should always **return** some string. But you are not returning a string. instead you are Writing it to the console using `WriteLine` method.

So Change

```
Console.WriteLine("Umbrella is selected");
```

to

```
return "Umbrella is selected";
```

**OR**

You can change your method's return type to `void`.

```
 public void myFunction(string Value)
 {
   //your current fancy stuff here
   Console.WriteLine("My method dont have a return type");
 }
```

**EDIT** : AS per the question edit.

`return` statement will take the control out from your method. that means the next line (`break`) won't be executed. So remove the break statement.

```
 case "Key Chain":
           return "Key Chain is selected";
```

Comment: Alternatively if you don't expect output from the function change the signature to a void and that should work as well.

Comment: @QuintinRobinson : Added that as well.

Comment: @Shyju It got rid of the error, but now I have "Unreachable Code detected error".

Comment: @Sarah: Your parameter name is `Value` and you are using `input` in the switch statement

Comment: @Shyju Returning on every case is bad practice. If possible a method should return once.

Answer (score 2):

Well... You don't return anything from your function, so change it to

```
public void myFunction(string Value)
```

Comment: Also, a valid option, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I heard of void maybe yesterday, I want it to return something.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class AddItemOptionOne
{
    //Methods that define class functionality
    public string myFunction(string input)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        switch (input)
        {
            case "Key Chain":
                result = "Key Chain is selected";
                break;
            case "Leather Armor":
                result = "Leather Armor is selected";
                break;
            case "Boots":
                result = "Boots is selected";
                break;
            case "Sword":
                result = "Sword is selected";
                break;
            default:
                result = "Input not reconized, please choose another item";
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 as possible approach... I would not keep strange `string input=Console.ReadLine();` line in answer...

Comment: Yep, that was a copy an paste. Updated as per suggestion.

Comment: I never knew you could do that, it will be useful to know. Thanks for helping me.